# Can someone double check if my truth table make sense to the problem statement?

Tags: circuit-design, truth-table

Just wanted to double-check. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Looks good.  Expression can be simplified.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

***To solve***

Create a Karnaugh Map (K-map) with your inputs and output.

[image: Karnaugh map]

Circle each group of 1's (or zeros) with the largest group you can until you have covered all 1's (or zeros).
Remember:

- Use a Gray code for row/col headers (only one bit changes between neighbouring cells)
- Circles can go over the end and wrap round.
- Circles can overlap.
- Make circles as large as you can
- Circles can only contain power of 2 (1,2,4,8,etc…) numbers of cells

[image: Circled map]

Write down what you see for each group, following these rules

- If a variable changes in a group then it's not included in the term.
- If a variables value is 0, then it's term is inverted
- The terms are products (logical AND)
- The result is the sum of products (logical OR)

e.g.

- In the red group the C term is both 0 and 1 so C is not included.
- In the green group, A changes so is not included.
- In the blue group A and C are both 1 but B changes so it is not included.

RED:  A.B
GREEN: B.C
BLUE: A.C

The minimal result:
X = A.B + B.C + A.C  (1)

But you get
X = A'.B.C + A.B'.C + A.B.C' + A.B.C  (2)

Which, if you notice, is just the sum of the smallest possible circles.

[image: Small circles]

**Q: Why are (1) and (2) not the same?

A: They are the same!**

(I will re-write this to make things easier to follow)
X = A.B.C' + A.B.C + A'.B.C + A.B'.C  (2)

To get from (1) to (2):
Remember A+A' = 1
So we can multiply out each term in (1) with the missing term and its negative, that's the same as ANDing with 1.

X = (A.B).(C+C') + (A+A').(B.C) + A.(B+B').C
X = <del>A.B.C</del> + A.B.C' + A.B.C + A'.B.C + <del>A.B.C</del> + A.B'.C

The A.B.C terms are common, so we can remove two of them and get
**X = A.B.C' + A.B.C + A'.B.C + A.B'.C**
Which is what we want.

Going the other way, from (2) to (1):

Our result is factors of ABC, so we need to remove all A'B'C' terms.

Group where ABC terms are common and add in more ABC terms if necessary

X = (A.B.C' + A.B.C) + (A'.B.C + A.B.C) + (A.B'.C + A.B.C)
X = (A.B).(C+C') + (A'+A).(B.C) + A.(B'+B).C
X = (A.B)(1) + (1)(B.C) + A.(1).C
**X = A.B + B.C + A.C**
Which is what we want.